# Templates inheritance and operators

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have the following code which causes problem when I call operator=() on a Property instance:

```
// myProperty.h.

template <class T, int typeFamily = TypeFamily<T>::value>
class PropertyImpl : public PropertyBase
{
    // Default template to catch errors.
};

template <class T>
class PropertyImpl<T, 0> : public PropertyBase
{
    // Data is part of the family of base types.
public:
    PropertyImpl(T* dataRef) : PropertyBase(), m_dataRef(dataRef) {}

    void operator=(T const & data) {*m_dataRef = data;}

protected:
    T* m_dataRef;
};

template <class T>
class Property : public PropertyImpl<T> {};
```

Note that `TypeFamily<>` is some meta-code computing whether T is a supported base type. `TypeFamily<T>::value` is 0 if T is a float.

Now I create an aggregated Property

```
// myNode.h.

class myNode
{
public:
    void setProp(float val) {m_prop = val;}

protected:
    Property<float> m_prop;
}
```

I was initially thinking that `Property<float>` deriving from `PropertyImpl<float, 0>` I would be able to call `m_prop = val`, as `operator=()` is defined for `PropertyImpl<float, 0>`. But my compiler returns the following error:

```
<myNode_path>(myNode_line) : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'float' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
3>        <myProperty_path>(myProperty_line): could be 'Property<T> &Property<T>::operator =(const MPC::Property<T> &)'
3>        with
3>        [
3>            T=float
3>        ]
3>        while trying to match the argument list '(Property<T>, float)'
3>        with
3>        [
3>            T=float
3>        ]
```

This is totally unclear to me, and I have the feeling I missed a fundamental behavior of templates. Or it is an easy catch right in front of my eyes...

Anyone understands what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Property` contains an implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator, which hides the one in the base class. You'll need a using-declaration to make it accessible:

```
template <class T>
class Property : public PropertyImpl<T> {
public:
    using PropertyImpl<T>::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Isn't there also a problem with the `template <class T> class Property : public PropertyImpl<T> {};`not heriting of `template <class T> class PropertyImpl<T, 0> : public PropertyBase {}` as OP expect ?

Comment: @Johan why doesn't it inherit?

Comment: @Simple It does inherit from `template <class T, int typeFamily = TypeFamily<T>::value> class PropertyImpl : public PropertyBase {};` not from the second one.

Comment: @Johan: If `value` is zero, as described, then it inherits from the partial specialisation for zero, as expected.

Comment: @Johan he stated that `float` gives a `typeFamily` of `0`. The default value of `TypeFamily<T>::value` doesn't need to be part of the specialisation.

Comment: @Simple and Mike Seymour: Thanks, I didn't understood that.

Comment: So one needs to use a `using` statement whenever using template inheritance?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Usually not. If you want to use something from the parent class - a single-argument conversion constructor or assignment operator - that would otherwise be hidden by an implicitly declared member, yes. But that's got nothing to do with whether templates are involved.